# Error while installing JSLintMate for Text Mate

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am trying to install JSLintMate http://rondevera.github.io/jslintmate/ for my text mate. Downloaded the bundle from their website and it suggested that it will get install automatically.

On unzipping it is asking for file encoding format and i am selecting default UTF-8

[image]

But after running the installation bundle I am getting an error

> The bundle “JavaScript JSLintMate 1.4.tmbundle” does not contain the
>   required “info.plist” file (or that file is corrupt) and can therefore
>   not be installed.

[image]

I searched on the web regarding this but not able to find the solution.

Text-Mate Version: 1.5.11 
OSX: Maverics 10.9 
JSLintMate: 1.4

Is there anything wrong from my side or some additional step is required to make it work? Also  please recommend me some alternatives since its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally its working.The problem is with the unarchiver utility only. If I use default archiver utility instead,it's perfectly working fine https://github.com/rondevera/jslintmate/issues/30